# iOS Swift: Help to understand this for loop function

Tags: swift, for-loop, swift2

I'm reading an iBook about Swift 2.2, and in a sample code, there is this function:

```
func minMax(array: [Int]) -> (min: Int, max: Int) {

    var currentMin = array[0]
    var currentMax = array[0]

    for value in array[1..<array.count] {

        if value < currentMin {
            currentMin = value
        }

        if value > currentMax {
            currentMax = value
        }
    }

    return (currentMin, currentMax)
}

let values = [21, 1, -4, 7, 2, 12, 88, 12021, 456]
let bounds = minMax(values)
```

I tried this piece of code but I don't understand how the for loop works here:

```
for value in array[1..<array.count]
```

Why don't write: `for value in array` instead ?
The only thing I noticed is with:

```
for value in array[1..<array.count]
```

it's looping 2 times to find the min and max number.
But using `for value in array`, 9 times of course.

Comment: > it's looping 2 times - what does it means? how do you calculate?

Comment: I tried in Playground and saw on the right side (2 times)

Comment: Oh no... My Playground shows me how many times my "if" statement is true... I put a print("") inside my loop and shows me 8 times... I understand now... Sorry for this stupid question :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first two lines of the function are already reading the first element:

```
var currentMin = array[0]
var currentMax = array[0]
```

So, there's no need to check it again. `array[1..<array.count]` returns all elements of the array **except** the first (notice that the range starts at `1` instead of `0`).

Comment: Oh my good ! Yes ^^ I see. But I don't understand how is it possible to find the min / max value in only 2 loops.

Comment: Possibly worth pointing out that you may use `array.dropFirst()` as an alternative to `array[1..<array.count]`, an alternative that possibly shows intent better.

Comment: Nice ! Thank you for this tip ! :)

Answer (score 2):

The loop shouldn't begin with the first array element because this first element is the current Min/Max reference.

That's why the loop starts at the second indexed element (the `1` in `[1..<array.count]`).

`array[1..<array.count]` is a slice of the array, going from the second element to the last.